# Formatted string in File.WriteAllText and File.Create

Tags: c#

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\Program Files\CopTablet\Report{0}.txt", textBox1);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

So with this, I'm trying to basically make a text file everytime the panel(used as button) is clicked with the name `Report{0}` but obviously that doesn't work.
The {0} would stand for `textBox1.Text` and that textbox basically contains a random number. So the end file would be called `Report(RandomNumber).txt`

And after that I want to write a var to it which I already have.
but again I'm not too sure how to do this.
I had something likes this but didn't work: `File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\CopTablet\Report{0}.txt", textBox1.Text, comb));`
The {0} directs to textBox1.Text again so you write in the file I just made and then the "comb" is the var that I want to write in the text file.

Comment: You must encompass your string with `String.Format("abcd{0}",.......);`.

Comment: "Obviously that doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem description in stackoverflow.  Also: if `File.Exists()` and `File.Create()` were accepting formattable strings, it would certainly be mentioned in their documentation.  Did you even bother to look at the documentation before bringing your problem to stackoverflow?

Comment: `File.Create(string.Format(@"C:\file{0}.txt", textBox1.Text));`

Comment: Add another small question I forgot to ask ^^

Comment: Already found it, nevermind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `String.Format` like:

```
String.Format(@"path\Report{0}.txt", textBox1.Text)
```

Or string interpolation like:

```
$@"path\Report{textBox1.Test}.txt"
```